# Texture descriptors in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

Does anyone know if OpenCV has some kind of texture descriptors implemented? I googled "opencv texture descriptors" but not much to see.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Gabor filter to extract texture descriptors

```
cv::Mat kernel = cv::getGaborKernel(cv::Size(kernel_size,kernel_size), sig, th, lm, gm, ps);
cv::filter2D(src_f, dest, CV_32F, kernel);
```

This is the C++ code, but it's the same for every other language. You have to get the Gabor filter kernel and than use the filter2d function.

I hope it helps

Comment: Oh yes I forgot Gabor filter. Thanks!